# IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code! in gecko driver log file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

While automating test cases through Firefox, I am getting an error:

> Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1

In geckoDriver.log there is an error:

> IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!

Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is tough to analyze the error in absence of the *version information* of the binaries you are using and exact *error stack trace*.

However this error message:

```
IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!
```

As per [IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410187) was observed with **Firefox v56.0** possibly due to either of the reasons:

- [Geckdriver keeps losing focus on the browser window when running multiple instances](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1002).
- Bad crashes in the IPC component.
- System running out of memory.

### Solution

- From *OS Architecture* perspective, there can be always only one single *OS Level Window* which can have focus at a time. So if a *Browser Instance* is currently not in focus and absolutely needs focus, you need to be switch.
- **Firefox 58.0a1** *nightly build* seems to have addressed the errors.
- Upgrading the *Browser Client* to recent *Firefox Quantum v60.0.1* will solve your issue.